# Angular2 rc1 Http Get

Tags: angular, angularjs-scope, angular2-services

I agree, one should not jump to new technologies when they are in beta stage, but its a good way to learn. However, which the recent changes in angular2, I am kinda stuck, as there is no helpful way to get http get calls working. I had this working before:

https://github.com/neoeahit/run_eat_travel/blob/master/app/services/RETService.ts

But now I am not sure how to move ahead with the new RC version. Anyone has any github links for angular2 http, more like a hello work example?

Comment: In your code almost nothing changes, only imports.

Comment: Thanks so much! got everything working!